# Как при отправке на сервер возраста, получить персону с датой рождения?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, postman

Как при отправке на сервер возраста (например 21) получить человека у которого год рождения совпадает с возрастом?

[image: База данных]

Я думал выгружать все записи с бд и проходить по всем, но, а если записей будет очень много, производительность спасибо не скажет...
Сразу в голову пришло 2 варианта:

1. Сначала узнаю год рождения(от переданного возраста), потом через формат привожу к LocalDate и сравниваю с датами из бд, но есть ещё день и месяц, идея и затухла;
2. Ещё вариант через sql запрос сравнивать только года, но не нашел внятного объяснение как это сделать. Везде сравнивают полную дату.

[image: sql запрос сравнение дат в бд]

Comment: в чем проблема, исходя из требуемого возраста, на беке определить диапазон дат рождения (минимальная и максимальная для данного возраста)и написать соответствующий запрос в базу?

Comment: "год рождения совпадает с возрастом" - уверен, что требуется совсем не это!

Comment: @Эникейщик почему ? Пользователь вводит возраст,к примеру 21 ,а сервер возвращает людей у которых год рождения 2002-хх-хх. Как по другому объяснить

Comment: А с каких пор 21 совпадает с 2002 или хотя бы даже с 2?

Comment: @Эникейщик 21- это полных лет, а 2002 это год рождения.

Comment: Ну что, как именно совпадают 21 и 2002? Нужно не "год рождения совпадает с возрастом", а просто людей с указанным возрастом.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, неправильно сформулировал вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избежать вычисления допустимого диапазона дат на стороне сервера БД с разными функциями, проще в JPA-репозитории создать метод с использованием условия BETWEEN:

```java
List<Person> findByBirthDateBetween(LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
```

который аналогичен JPQL-запросу:

```java
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.BirthDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2")
List<Person> getPersons(LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
```

и реализовать дефолтный вызов такого метода для заданного возраста в годах:

```java
default List<Person> byAge(int years) {
    return findByBirthDateBetween(
        LocalDate.now().minusYears(years),
        LocalDate.now().minusYears(years - 1)
    );
}
```